# Отображение данных с устройств в режиме реального времени

Tags: веб-программирование, com, tcp

Столкнулся с такой задачей, решение которой пока не приходит на ум.
Имеется Web-сервер и некий компьютер в сети, к которому подключено некое устройство. Данные с этого устройства я получаю с COM-порта (обновляются ~1 раз в 5 сек). Хочется отображать эти данные на сайте, не записывая их в БД. 
Или записывание (обновление одной записи в таблице) в БД с такой частотой - это нормально?
Как обновлять данные AJAXом я знаю. Вопрос в том, как их получить с удалённого хоста? 
У меня есть пара вариантов:

1. TCP-клиент (Web-сервер), TCP-сервер (комп с устройством). Или UDP.
2. Простейший Web-сервер на компе с устройством с выдачей JSON, например.
3. DCOM?

Или всё-таки писать в какую-то временную таблицу в БД с интервалом 1 раз в 5 сек? или просто увеличить интервал?

Answer (score -1):

Я бы начал слушать ком-порт и каким-то легковестным способом передавал это на боевой сервак. Это позволит абстрагироваться и не сильно зависить от подобной машины, так как часто их ставят в сложных условиях, да и саму машинку можно заменить при желании на малинку или бананчик. И никаких проблем с базами данных, клиентами, сетью и прочим хайлоадом. А уже на боевом серваке можно все это писать в базу на много гигабайтов, строить графики и анализы, раздавая миллионам клиентов через аяксы и вебсокеты, рисуя баннеры-информеры и рассылая смс с лунапарком и поэтессами.

В качестве транспорта я бы выбрал что-то легкое, к примеру UDP, если есть такая возможность. Если такой возможности нет, то я бы попробовал использовать какой-то чатик, вроде XMPP или модный нынче Телеграмм.

Comment: Так в этом и вопрос. Писать ли в базу? Передать-то я смогу по UDP, например. А дальше? Как сделать так, чтоб вэб-сервер получил эти данные? С записью в БД всё понятно. А как сделать так, чтобы не записывать в БД/файл? Как выдать данные вэб-серверу?

Comment: Ок, значит у нас вебсервер и принимающая сторона на сервере, со стабильным каналом. Это половина решения, с ней определились. Чтобы эти данные воткнуть в веб, нам надо как-то показать/передать их вебсерверу, ну или как-то сделать доступными ему. Например, можно сохранить в текстовый файл и потом его через веб поллить. Кстати, древние железки подключались по FTP и сами клали файлы, с которыми работали их веб-части. Можно использовать модный нынче пабсаб, реализованный в некоторых веб-серверах, можно вообще накрутить свой вариант (продолжение поста далее)

Comment: Свой вариант модуля к веб-серверу или даже свой вебсервер, который параллельно слушает UDP-пакеты. Это несложно, есть библиотеки для эмбеддинга веб-серверов почти на каждом языке, а если боязно такое в интернет выставлять - всегда есть прокси_пасс у чего-то стабильного и явно протестированного. Писать ли такое в базу - зависит от того, нужны ли эти данные потом, скажем для аналитики. Если нет - то делать им в базе нечего, проще писать в текстовый файлик и раздавать его через вебсервер.

Comment: Сейчас в процессе переезда на новый сервер. По задумке делаю так:

Comment: 1. На вэб-сервере запущен UDP-сервер, который слушает порт и распознаёт команды на сохранение данных и выдачу данных. 2. На компе с железякой UDP-клиент, который получает данные с COM-порта и отправляет вэб-серверу по таймеру. 3. На вэб-сервере (использую django) вььюха по отображению текущих показаний будет создавать UDP-запрос к серверу, получать данные и отображать их. Как-то так. Пока протестировал связку Комп с железкой - Вэб-сервер по UDP.

Comment: Как-то слишком сложно, проще файлик подкладывать